# Android How to access variables or objects from an override method of another class to another class

Tags: android, overriding

I have a class named PracticeAdapter, and it has an override method `public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)` which contains `holder.itemView`. I want to access this `holder.itemView` in another class named PracticeSteps, and in there set its background color.

How can I achieve this? This is code that I have:

PracticeSteps Class:

```
public class PracticeSteps extends Fragment {

public void checkOrderOfProcedures(){
    mItemArray = new ArrayList<>();
    mDragListView.setDragListListener(new DragListView.DragListListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onItemDragEnded(final int fromPosition, final int toPosition) {
            if (Long.valueOf(toPosition).equals((Long)(mItemArray.get(toPosition).first))) {
                Toast.makeText(mDragListView.getContext(), "Correct position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //SET THE BACKGROUND COLOR OF holder.itemView in here

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mDragListView.getContext(), "Incorrect position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    setupListRecyclerView();
}
```

PracticeAdapter Class:

```
public class PracticeItemAdapter extends DragItemAdapter<Pair<Long, String>, PracticeItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    String text = mItemList.get(position).second;
    holder.mText.setText(text);
    holder.itemView.setTag(text);
    //ACCESS THE holder.itemView from here
}
```

Comment: First of all in your fragment create adapter and pass data from fragment to PracticeItemAdapter  then set adapter RecyclerView..

Comment: @User6829548 could you show me how to do it?

Comment: Are you using a recycler view for accomplishing this ?